# Xamarin.Forms ExportRenderer vs ExportCell

Tags: xamarin.forms, renderer

I am trying to get better understanding of Xamarin.Forms renderers.  I know what they are.  They create a native view based on input from Xamarin Forms.  You put in a Xamarin Forms ViewCell, and you get back a Android View or iOS UITableViewCell, or Windows DataTemplate.  I get that.

But I have seen code using `ExportRenderer` and other code using `ExportCell` and I dont know what is the difference.  When to use one over the other?

Xamarin documentation/page search is not finding either one.

They usage is identical:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyXamarinFormsElementType), typeof(MyNativeRendererType))]

[assembly: ExportCell(typeof(MyXamarinFormsElementType), typeof(MyNativeRendererType))]
```

In fact, in my code, I have a `ListView` with `ItemCellRenderer` and I tried adding either of these two assembly attributes and there is no visible difference.

As I said, Xamarin API provides zero information on this.

Comment: I'd guess that ExportCell performs a similar function to ExportRenderer, but optimized for just Cell types.

Comment: That was my guess too but then I looked at the examples of rendering ViewCell and they use ExportRenderer.  More interestingly, Xamarin API provides zero info on either

Comment: if you look at the XF source, the cell version is only used in a few cases.  It may be deprecated?